# How to retrieve data received from AJAX call. Got Undefined

Tags: ajax, leaflet

[image]Having tough times trying to deal with data (see markersMethod). Got undefined. All declared logs work fine. In order to clarify the problem, I 
 provide some code from 3 files related to the ajax call.
This question is NOT a duplicate because the previous was about making ajax call(I figured it out by myself) then it was closed. The actual question deals with handling already made ajax call in the controller side. As you see, these questions are completely different although they share some parts of code.

```
 markers.ejs file

       function onMapClick(e) {
             coords = e.latlng;
             marker = L.marker(coords);
             marker.addTo(map);
             foo(coords)
       }
       function foo(coord){
             $.ajax({
             url:'/markers',
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {coordinates: JSON.stringify(coord)},
             success: function(data, text, jqXHR) {
                  alert(data);
             },
             error: function(req, status, error) {
                  alert(status, error);
             }
        });
      }


 markersControllers.js file 

        markersMethod: (req, res) => {
        data = req.data;
        console.log(req)
        console.log('req received');

 main.js file 

        router.post('/markers', markersController.markersMethod)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't handle an AJAX call. Got 'ERROR' callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508641/cant-handle-an-ajax-call-got-error-callback)

Comment: @IvanSanchez This question is NOT a duplicate because the previous was about making ajax call(I figured it out by myself) then it was closed. The actual question deals with handling already made ajax call in the controller side. As you see, these questions are completely different although they share some parts of code.

Comment: Where in the code did you get 'undefined'?

Comment: @peeebeee In markersMethod I got ReferenceError: data is not defined when I include this line data = req.data; But without this line console.log(req) works well I can see posted coordinates.

Comment: @peeebeee I've uploaded a picture,  check it out if you're don't mind.

Comment: You don't need to call `JSON.stringify()` on the `data` object - `$.ajax` will handle converting the object to JSON for you since you specified `dataType: json`.

Comment: @peeebeee This answer is simple.  I forgot to declare let data; So  the working code will be   markersMethod: (req, res) => {
          let data;
      data= req.body.coordinates
      console.log(data)
      console.log('req received')}.                                             
  Thank you for giving me a helpful hand!